# How to position DataTables TableTools controls when using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dom, datatables

How can I change the position of DataTables controls  when using Twitter Bootstrap theme?

I am using also the following plugins:

- ColReorder
- TableTools

**sDom**

```
sDom: 'T<"clear">lRfrtip',
```

**Table:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#table').DataTable( {
        sDom: 'T<"clear">lRfrtip',
        sScrollY: "200px",
        sScrollX: "100%",
        oTableTools: {
            "sSwfPath" :"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
            "aButtons": [ "copy","csv","xls", "print" ]
        }
    } );
});
```

Working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/vdpLm1ow/

**PROBLEM**
I am trying to achieve the following:

```
|Show |25|entries     |COPY|CSV|XLS|PRINT|    Search|_______|             
-------------------------------------------------------------
|Header 1 |Header 2 |Header 3 |Header 4 |Header 5 |Header 6 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|         |         |         |         |         |         |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|         |         |         |         |         |         |
-------------------------------------------------------------
Showing 1 to 1 of 1 entries                  |Prev | 1 |Next|
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

You need to use the following [dom](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option to center TableTools buttons between page length and filter controls.

```js
dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-4'T><'col-sm-4'f>>R" +
     "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
     "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
```

Also add the following CSS rule:

```css
div.DTTT_container {
  float:none;
  text-align:center;
}
```

**DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vdpLm1ow/3/) for code and demonstration.

**NOTE**

You're using DataTables 1.10 so I have updated option names (`sDom` -> `dom`), see [this conversion guide](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert) for more details.

Comment: This has to be added to the datatable documentation. I couldn't find anything about it. Thank you very much indeed

Comment: @QuentinTanioartino, I agree, this should have been documented on [Bootstrap styling](http://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) page, that the plug-in depends on `dom` option.